# Please make PayPal payments possible in Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am really sorry, but I don't give my credit card data to anybody.

The reason doesn't matter. The disadvantages I incur don't matter. How much I trust them doesn't matter.

Not even PayPal has my credit card data.

The only place I am willing to give my credit card data is the site of my own bank or credit card company.

I would like to pay Stack Exchange; I trust it, but I will not share my credit card number with the site under any circumstances.

Please enable a way to pay for Teams via PayPal.

Comment: Perhaps broaden this a bit? There are other options besides just Paypal, and I've heard a few companies that refuse to use Paypal because they've been screwed in the past. So, for example, "Please allow non-credit card payment options for Teams"

Comment: @peterh we anticipate offering an invoicing option in the future.

Comment: @Kendra I think a company wanting customers, should really be not so choosy.

Comment: Peterh, I'd suggest rewording the feature request a bit. I suspect the downvotes are because of the negativity towards CC payments. This distracts from the point of the feature request: Different payment options.

Comment: @Kendra Well, I have my bank account number on some paper contracts. That I can tolerate, but I won't give this data to the Internet.

Comment: @peterh A company wanting customers just needs to have different options, not necessarily Paypal. They can be as choosy as they want, in the interest of protecting their business. I've seen plenty of successful companies reject Paypal. Granted, they are smaller, but they were small before they moved off Paypal. All I'm saying is, it doesn't necessarily have to be Paypal to make this better.

Comment: @Cerbrus The important thing is, the reason is that I simply don't share my CC card number on the Internet. Not even for people/companies I trust - even if I can trust their goodwill, I can't trust the security of all of them, until the eternity. Furthermore, I read though 100 page long "Terms of Service" and analyze them with a lawyer knowing well the U.S. law. Thus, the only way for me to make me paying on the Internet, if it is a prepaid service, I pay *before* I would use the service, and if I don't pay in any circumstances, then the contract will be revoked automatically,

Comment: @Cerbrus without any possibility of the service provider to charge me later for anything.

Comment: @peterh: But that's not really relevant to this feature request, is it? _"Please add more options to pay, instead of CC. I don't want to use a CC."_ is a _very_ good reason already. Especially considering the fact it's not that "normal" to _have_ a credit card, everywhere.

Comment: @Cerbrus Do you know any similar zero-knowledge solution for internet paying? I would be happy if paypal would have a concurrent.

Comment: Well, in the Netherlands, we have [iDeal](https://www.ideal.nl/en/), which is basically a direct payment from your bank / account to the other party. Nothing needs to be "pre-paid", nor does the other party get anything from you but your name and money.

Comment: To answer your "are there other zero-knowledge solutions" question, you could also leverage Google Pay and have that money come out of a bank account.  I *believe* they create a virtual card for you anyway so you could use it like a credit card, though.

Comment: @user1114 First, as a company, you need to have such terms of services and pricing, what doesn't forbid "abuse" (in the sense of over-using the service), but makes it better paying. For example, if a user creates 20million questions by you with a script, I think it is reasonable to allow it - but only after they paid for it. In more serious cases, you can terminate the contract with them. Or what abuse are you talking about?

Comment: You don't trust Paypal with your CC but you trust it with your bank account?

Comment: @0xFF There's not a lot Paypal can do with your bank account number - apart from pay money into it.  They could set up an unauthorized direct debit from the account, but a) the bank will reverse it directly; b) they would then be in a *world* of hurt.

Comment: @MartinBonner AFAIK, pretty much the same would happen with a credit card no? In my experience CC transactions are very easy to reverse.

Comment: @0xFF Even easier, in fact, and they come with quite a bit of fraud protection on the consumer's side which does not exist for checking/savings accounts. If someone defrauds your CC, you will not be on the hook for much or any of the money. If someone defrauds your savings or checking account... sorry, that money is gone.

Comment: @peterh Most companies don't accept PayPal as a form of payment for B2B transactions. I don't think this makes them "choosy", it's just not necessary when there are easier, safer, and more ubiquitous methods of payments available.

Comment: @0xFF No.  Credit card companies have, in the past, refused to reverse Paypal transactions.  (You *did* ask Paypal to take some money from your account; the fact Paypal then gave it to a thieving scammer, is not the CC co's problem.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Fair enough. In the context of this question, I was mostly thinking about unwanted but pre-authorised payments on Paypal, like, say, accidentally accepting a recurring payment.

Comment: @MartinBonner It is already long surreal. I shouldn't be able to ask PayPal to take money from my account, *because it shouldn't have any access to my bank account*. Except if I was enough careless to give them such a permission.

Comment: @0xFF The PayPal can't see my bank account, I don't have an associated bank account to my PayPal account. I load my PayPal account by sending money to the PayPal from the website of my bank. The PayPal can only see a bank account, from which money arrived to my PayPal account. It has now way to know if it is even mine or not, and has also no permission to do with it anything.

Comment: @TylerH Safe? You give permission to a big multi company far away, to get money from you *for his initiative*, and it is safe? I think the only way to do this safely, if the only way to get money from you, if you personally authorize *all* transactions, *by your bank*.

Comment: @peterh Your bank is just another company like a credit card company is. They are both required to adhere to the exact same privacy and security standards with regard to your credit card information.

Comment: @TylerH The difference is that my bank only handles my money, but I don't pay them (except some small fees). Anybody I pay, should be obviously different entity than the entity handling my money. Would you ever use a tank station where the gas price is determined by the seller, retroactively, on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Note that to get Chinese customers, you'll need to support Wechat Pay, Alipay or UnionPay.

Comment: @peterh That's not true; you pay the bank all the money you have stored with them. They then use that money to make loans and investments. That's how they make money and stay in business. They are able to always give you "your" money when you ask for it in person because regulations typically require that they keep X dollars in cash on hand. But they don't take your cash and then put it in a box and never touch it until you come asking for it... that's not how banking works. Banking is a *big* business.

Comment: @TylerH It is entirely false, the money on my bank account is my money and not the property of the bank. Furthermore, I consider your comment hairsplitting and it is not nice.

Comment: @peterh Look, any introductory course in banking will show you that I'm not making this up. I'm sorry you don't believe me. Just know that your money may be your money legally, but that doesn't mean you'll always get it. That's what made the stock market crash of 1929 in the United States so bad. Everyone went to withdraw "their money" from the banks and the banks didn't have it because (surprise) that's not how banking works. Even today US banks are only required to have enough cash to dispense up to a certain amount of your money when you ask for it.

Comment: @peterh I don't care what you think of me, but there's no need to be rude. Remember the site code of conduct is [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). As for user styles, look for a browser addon like Stylish or Violentmonkey.

Comment: Why do you even own a credit card if you never use it for payments? I assume a store you pay at would be no more "trustworthy" than any other company, no matter if online or not.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFDe5kUUyT0&t=1557s

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9IH-XKQpOI

Comment: @Adrian I don't use it for payments on the internet. But this whole thing is totally off-topic. What is ontopic here, is that I don't give my CC number to anybody on the Internet, and I can pay for that everywhere. Where I can't, there I don't buy anything. Well, maybe not I will be the largest SE customer, but no rational company would be so choosy in this sense.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes, roughly so. Also this is an important factor. Another important factor is Rel 13:15-18. But what here matters, are not these. I would only buy something from a company, I would be happy to pay for it, and... watch also the terrible mass of bullshitting what the people reacted here.

Comment: @peterh yup I understand, only linked them so you understand what Tyler was talking about _They then use that money to make loans and investments. That's how they make money and stay in business_

Comment: @PeterHaddad I admit I didn't read his last comment, because I couldn't consider him having a cooperative attitude. Also I can't imagine, how would this whole thing relevant below the post. This post is about that I ask the SE to have paypal support, because I will not share my CC on the internet under no circumstances, and likely not I am the only one.

Comment: @peterh: But Paypal isn't necessary; what you really want is to continue to push money from your bank account rather than having companies pull it on their own schedule.  That could be accomplished by using your bank to push money directly to Stack Exchange (or any other company) without going through Paypal along the way.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes - if my own authorization is required for all induvidual transactions.

Comment: @peterh: My banks' Online Bill Pay features work that way (I can authorize individual transfers or schedule them in advance, with the ability to cancel up until processing starts).  For most payees, the transfer completes electronically in 2-3 business days, so it is just as speedy as Paypal or credit cards, probably even faster.  And I can attach an account number so the receiver knows which account to apply the payment to.  Based on the same ACH clearinghouse you're probably already using to transfer into your Paypal account.

Comment: Given that capability through the bank, I don't see why you would want to involve Paypal, who have somewhat of a reputation for seizing funds that people trusted them with.  The recipient can't start any new transactions through the system -- if they could convince a court that you owed money and the court ordered garnishment, they could perhaps take that court order to the bank and save some time finding your account using the transaction number from one of the transactions you authorized -- having an intermediary wouldn't prevent that process, and probably not slow it down very much.

Comment: PayPal isn't trustworthy either.

Comment: @yughred This is why not even the Paypal knows my bank account number and card number, and I upload it with a third-party provider (which does it by also not knowing my banking data).

Comment: @Catiger3331 (Sorry for the late react) That is right - this is why not even they know my CC data. I load my balance by them through an intermediary provider (who knows both my account number and paypal account, but can't do anything with it), and there is only a little sum on my paypal at once. And yes, it happened already even on a big provider (ebay) that I clicked accidentally and finally I had to pay for something I did not want to buy.

Comment: @TylerH (Sorry for the late react) I know how the banking works, at least [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserve_requirement) part is well known to me, but it has nothing to do with the post. I simply don't pay on the internet with Cc: card and so is it. (Actually I don't even have a Cc: card, what I have is a debit card, so if some stealing would happen, at least it could not happen for the credit limit, only to until the sum I loaded it. You can't imagine how hard was it to let understand with wonderful bank employee, that *no I won't get credit from them on any circumstances*)